# Most noble character on GoT

Tags: discussion

Now that we are nearing the end of Game of Thrones, would it be entirely off-topic to argue the "most noble character" on the main, or would that be completely POB? If so, how could the Q be phrased better?

Is it even possible we could set up some kind of voting system?

Comment: http://www.wetpaint.com/whos-most-noble-character-1-795242/ - Behold, an entire article of opinion with little or no objective evidence

Comment: To start with, shouldn't the asker define quality what he means by "noble"? In the setting of *Game of Thrones* (which I never read or watched any of) is "nobility" about being high-born, or is it about being of good moral character?

Comment: @user14111 - Hence why we need to avoid questions that focus on the nature of nobility and keep to objective measures like what the author said or whether any characters are described as being especially noble in the books/interviews/whatever

Answer (score 1):

You need to phrase it in a way that's *quantifiable* rather than merely soliciting  people's opinions about which they think are the most noble.

Something like;

> Which character *does GRRM think* is most noble?

or

> Which character is *described as* most noble in-universe?

Comment: erm...could you possibly expand on the second? I think was basically my point.

Comment: I'm gonna ask both..txs

Comment: @Cascabel - Well, for example has any character been referred to as being the noblest? We certainly have multiple examples of those who've been described as villainous

Comment: @Cascabel - Both are non-opinion-based and potentially excellent questions.

Comment: so sorry, but I have not read the books. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Cascabel - In that case, there's potentially a third; "*Which character do the producers of the GoT show think is the most noble?"*

Comment: should WE post 3 separate Qs? I,m gonna do the one about JRRM

Comment: @Cascabel - It's up to you. Might I suggest you post *one* and see how well it's received. There's always time to ask more and you may find that the answer for one also covers questions you were planning to ask in future on the same theme.

Comment: done...plz see the Q and feel free to edit. I think it should be a community effort. rep is of little importance to me, only the ideas.